# C++ - How to get the desktop path OF A SPECIFIC USER

Tags: c++, file, shell, path, desktop

I'm looking for a way to get the desktop path of a specific user in c++. I googled it, and found heaps of anwers, but all of them (using SHGetFolderPath) give me the desktop path of the current user. I could get a list of users with NetUserEnum. Also, it would be great if it works on Windows 2000/XP but that's not necessary. Thanks ;)

```
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_DESKTOP,NULL,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,PATH);
    printf(path);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve current user path via system environment constants 
RUN -> CMD -> type "Set appdata"
the cmd will echo the path of application data folder then you can split this string 
by "\" and get user path 
i think this is the most easy way to do that 
call cmd in c++ and pass the "set appdata" to it as parameter and get the output 
then do what ever you want to retrieve current user path

Comment: if you have current user path then simply add "\Desktop" and you will get the Desktop folder path
or you can use 
'set userprofile' to get current user folder path this will be better

Comment: How do I get the desktop path for an user that is not currently logged on?

Comment: you can't do that by normal methods because of permissions that will not allow you to access any other -Not logged- user folders so you should use api's function to help you in this but the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList provide incomplete list of users you can get the value ProfileImagePath to get the folder path of that user take a look in youre regedit and you will see that hope this help you